# PHP Mysql Update Serialize Array in escape apostrophe

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I have a problem for php mysql update serialized data.

**My Serialized data**

```
a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:5:"image";s:4:"5812";s:5:"title";s:14:"Day 1 : LOREM";s:4:"desc";s:416:"Lorem Ipsum is 'simply dummy' text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500's, when an unknown printer ";}}
```

Problem is in the text like, **'simply dummy'** for apostrophe.

**Mysql Update statement**

```
$conSave="update serialized_data set value='$str1' where id='{$_POST['key_id']}'";
$conSaveData = mysql_query($conSave);
```

How can I solve this problem in serialized data?

**MySQLi Update Statement**

```
$stmt =  $con->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare("Update serialized_data set value=? WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$a,$b);
$a = $str1;
$b = $_POST['key_id'];

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: String values need escaping before inserting into an SQL statement,, to convert quotes to a form that won't break the query

Comment: But storing serialised data in a database isn't generally recommended

Comment: And you should really be using MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements/bind variables.... it is 2015 now after all.... and then you wouldn't need to escape strings

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks for reply.I try to use for MySQLi update  bind_param and execute but serialized data broken after update...

Comment: Perhaps you should show the code that you're using for MySQLi with bind parameters

Comment: if you are planing to use `unserialize` and `serialize` you may run into some issues. I would store json string into the database. But before you do that you should using PDO or mysqi extension to prepare your query.  another thing you can do is $str = str_replace("'", "''", $str);

Comment: @MarkBaker add to MySQLi update statement...

Comment: @boozer87 the 2 lines `$a = $str1;
$b = $_POST['key_id']; `should be before `$stmt->bind_param("ss",$a,$b);`

Comment: @Mike thank you, but not changing anything when to use for MySQLi update serialized data is broken...

Comment: @Mike another solutions it is worked, but what a problem for MySQLi update statement ?

Comment: @boozer87 I don't know what you mean by breaking? what is the error that you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code should look like this

```
try {
   $b = $_POST['key_id'];

   $stmt = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
   $stmt->prepare("Update serialized_data set value=? WHERE id = ?");
   $stmt->bind_param("si",$str1, $b);
   $stmt->execute();

} catch(Exception $e){
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

However, I would rather use `json` string instead of serialized string.

Something like this

```
$data = array('key' => 'val');  // this is your original array before you serialize it
$a = json_encode($data);  //this will convert your array to a json string
```

then when you select the string from the database, you will use `json_decode($selectedString); // this will convert your json string into an object`